# PhpStorm perform case sensitivity?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, phpstorm, case-sensitive

I have two folders in GitHub:

```text
- Client
- client
```

But in PhpStorm on Mac I get data exist only inside `Client` folder and not both `client` and `Client`.

[image]

I try the command of git:

```
git mv --force src/stores/client/clientInformationDetails.ts src/stores/Client/clientInformationDetails.ts
```

Comment: What operating system are you running?  Do you control the project and want to change them to be the same folder, or is it intentional and desired that there are two different folders?

Comment: HFS+, the OSX filesystem, *can* be configured to be case sensitive, unfortunately by default however it is not.  You simply can't have both `client` and `Client` on the default configuration of a Mac filesystem.

Comment: i use macOS i need to make them inside one folder (Client)